# How to show data in multiple lines in jspdf autotable?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, jspdf-autotable

I'm using jspdf autotable to create pdf file.I want to show data in multiple lines.How can i show the data in multiple lines using jspdf autotable.

```
 var item1=this.dataa;

    var columns1 = ["EXPERIENCE"];
    var rows1 = [];



    for(let i=0; i<item1.length; i++){
      var temp1 = [item1[i].field2];
      var temp2 = [item1[i].field5_date];
      var temp5 = [item1[i].field4];


      rows1.push(temp1,temp2,temp5);
    }

    doc.autoTable(columns1, rows1,
      {
        margin: {left:300},

      });
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can include a `\n` character in your text and the text will be broken into two.